# Vertically Center floated elements with respect to their parents

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to vertically center a floated element with respect to its parent. Here is my css:

```
.custom{
    float:left;
    padding:0px 4px;
    color:yellow;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
}

.anchor{
    clear:left;
    padding:10px 0px;
    position:relative;
    color:red;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
}

.clearfix:after {
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
   content: " ";
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}

.vcenter{
    color:blue;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
}
```

And here is an (updated) fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6TVGb/5/

Ideally, I would like to vertically center the blue elements (Homestead Exemption on the fiddle, vcenter in the css) with respect to the red elements (anchor in the css).

Fixing/hard-coding any heights is out of the question, which is making a solution really hard to find.

Comment: Please take advantage of code indention standards (4 spaces); it makes your code readable for other people. I'm referring to the Fiddle code, for anyone wondering.

Comment: It is generated code, which is why it isn't properly indented. I'll go through it and fix it now.

Comment: Yea, I was just looking at your fiddle and was about to ask you to clean that up too...

Comment: @TylerH Just click the TidyUp button and it will be to your liking

Comment: Not the best solution but you can change the *line-height:*px;* of each one of blue elements.

Comment: @ChrisM Cool, never used that feature before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `table` and `table-cell`.  Using your `.clearfix` div as the wrapper, then wrap each div inside `.clearfix` with another div with the class `.cell`.  set `.clearfix` to `display:table;` and set `.cell` to `display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;`.  Also delete the `.clearfix:after` rule-set

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/6TVGb/8/)

css:

```
.clearfix {
    display:table;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

html:

```
<div class='clearfix'>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class='custom vcenter'>Primary Land Use
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class='custom'>
             <input type- 'text'/>
               <br/>
             <select data-bind="options: $$availabledt$0000000002, optionsText: 'name', selectedOptions: $dt$0000000002"></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
         <div class='vcenter custom'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! I'm marking it as answered because the fiddle looks great and removing the clearfix:after rule shouldn't negatively affect anything else.